# Storing DataFrame with python objects as data in an HDF store

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

To keep track of models and all their parameters I train for a specific task, I want to store all relevant information in a database. Because I am familiar with pandas, I chose HDF for this purpose. However, I am running into problems storing python objects.

I have the following function to store a model with its parameters to the database (the HDF store):

```
import pandas as pd

def store_model_to_database():

    data = {
        'model name' : model_name, # string
        'model' : model, # python object (keras model)
        'file' : model_store_path, # string
        'optimizer' : optimizer, # string
        'loss' : loss, # string
        '#epochs' : epochs, # int
        'batch size' : batch_size, # int
        'accuracy' : accuracy, # float
        'history' : history # python object
    }

    store = pd.HDFStore('data/model_store.h5', 'a')
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([data])
    store.append('data', df)
```

For every python object in the dataframe upon calling `store.append` I will get an error of the form

> TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [field] because its data
>   contents are [mixed] object dtype

where `<field>` is one of either `model` or `history`.

But as far as I know HDF stores can store any data, including python objects. What is necessary to successfully write python objects to an HDF store with pandas?

Comment: If you want to try out writing a dataframe to `HDF` file try this : `df.to_hdf('test.h5', key='df', mode='w')`. And if want to some other object to it `s = pd.Series([1,5,6])` you can do this `s.to_hdf('data.h5', key='s')`

Comment: What if I want to add another dataframe of the same format to the dataframe at key `df`?

Comment: Then give `append` to the sentence `s.to_hdf('test.h5', key='df', append=True)`. Check if this works for you.

Comment: for that I need format `'table'`. But when I do `df.to_hdf('store.hf', key='df', mode='w', format='table')` I get the exact error I was talking about in my question.